# Why does java have a primitive char?

Tags: java, types, char

As I've been learning about a few different languages, I've seen that java is the only one with a "char" datatype. For example, charAt() for javascript returns a string whereas in java the method returns a character. Is there a reason for a "character" datatype and why don't other languages use them?

Comment: Java inherited the concept of having a `char` primitive from C/C++ like languages.

Comment: Many other languages *do* have a `char` data type. You should perhaps be asking yourself rather why Javascript doesn't.

Comment: JavaScript have similar notion of "char" as other languages with `String.charCodeAt(i)` returning `Number` type (which is only other basic type supported by JavaScript), but it is very close to most languages notion of `char` as 8/16bit integer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to say and ask myself

for `char a='a';`  & `String a="a";`

```
How much memory does a char variable takes ?
```

and

```
How much memory does a string literal or string object takes ?
```

If you figure this out , Then this answers your question

Comment: @TheNewIdiot me neither :P

Comment: Char is more memory efficient, but what is a use case where storing characters individually rather than a long string is going to unplug a bottleneck?  EG if I store the genome as a long string, is that saving me overhead over storing three billion characters separately?  I get the idea, but don't see the application

Answer (score 1):

[James Gosling told me](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

> Most of the time, if you are using a single character value, you will use the primitive char type.

For example:

```
char ch = 'a';
```